# Macros on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with macros in Excel. What I am trying to do is add 8 and 1/2 hours of time to range of cells. So, in one range of cells have different times like 7:00 AM or 3:30 PM and the cell next to it I would like to add 8 and 1/2 hour to it. I couldn't figure out how to add time using macros. I need it for range of cells. So add 8 and 1/2 hours to range("C4:C400") and put the value to range("D4:D400"). In range("C4:C400") the value is 7:00 AM or 3:30 PM, so adding 8 and 1/2 hours to range("D4:D400") would be 3:30 PM or 12:00 AM.

I would really really appreciate if someone could help me with this. 
Thanks

Comment: You might want to include the code you have so it is easier to help you.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to SuperUser, but in order to add 8.5 hours to a date/time value, add `+(8.5/24)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dateAdd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateadd-function) to do this:

```
Sub addtime()
    For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("C1:C400")
        rngCell.Offset(, 1).Value = DateAdd("n", 30, DateAdd("h", 8, rngCell))
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
with worksheets("sheet1").range("D4:D400")
    .formula = "=c4+time(8, 30, 0)"
    'optionally revert the formulas to the returned values
    '.value = .value
end with
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. I was able to figure it out.